# Push notification using onesignal in loopback

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback, onesignal

Hi i'm trying to integrate onesignal push notification in loopback but i can't figure out the logic behind that and totally lost. so i need some support from you friends . Thanks in advance ...

Comment: Hey @sunilsmith, think you could maybe describe a bit more about what you're trying to do? It's tough to understand the end goal here :) Are you just trying to send push notifications using OneSignal?

Answer (score 0):

U can use :

1. use function remote method function "after save" in loopback
2. so, if you success save data on database, and call the function onesignal create notification.